# how to make the line ok?

Tags: php

```
$lc_button.=$lc_button.'<div class="buttonRow forward">'.<?php echo zen_submit(BUTTON_IMAGE_ADD_PRODUCTS_TO_CART, BUTTON_ADD_PRODUCTS_TO_CART_ALT, 'id="submit1" name="submit1"'); ?>.
      '</div>';
```

it shows an error on it. but i don't know where it is and how to correct it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already in the PHP context and then you try to enter again with the PHP opening tag (`<?php`).

Your line should look like...

```
$lc_button .= $lc_button . '<div class="buttonRow forward">' . zen_submit(BUTTON_IMAGE_ADD_PRODUCTS_TO_CART, BUTTON_ADD_PRODUCTS_TO_CART_ALT, 'id="submit1" name="submit1"'); . '</div>';
```